# How to call a controller method from jsp in Spring mvc using onchange method

Tags: java, javascript, spring, jsp, spring-mvc

> I have a Spring mvc project with an html form in jsp.
>   The form has a date field which I have to validate. 
>   But, we cannot enter an already existing date in the database, so I want to get that message to the web page when we enter an already existing date.

- I have to call back end java methods to check that. How can I do that?
- What is the way to call a back end java method when we enter a Date field ?
- How can we use onchange method for that?

Comment: First thing to understand is that you are not _calling a back end java method_. You are sending an HTTP request to an HTTP server which will respond (by calling your java method and a few others) with an HTTP response.

Comment: thank you very much. but i am not familiar with HTTP request? can you hep me?

Comment: You need to start learning the `Web application` tutorials . start with `jee` before looking into spring

Answer (score 0):

To make the example a bit better understandable, I assume that you will create an "Event" that has a start date.

The Spring MVC way is to have a Controller with two methods:

- `createEventFrom` mapped to /myform with HTTP Request GET - that provides the empty form
- `createEvent` second one mapped to /myform too but with with HTTP Request POST (or PUT) - that takes the request from the Browser that containing the form data entered by the user.

The Point is that the `createEvent` method need to check whenever or not the user input is valid. When it is valid then it creates the Event and (for example) redirect the user to the show page. But when the input is not valid, than it render the create page again (with the already existing user input) and some error message for the user that he can not use this date.

Answer (score 0):

The good approach is to use ajax call by onChange method in jsp. You will get help in following link http://www.beingjavaguys.com/2013/07/sending-html-form-data-to-spring.html about Spring MVC,Ajax and jQuery.